# Is there any aws-java-sdk to do s3-distcp?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3distcp

I would like to do s3-distcp from my code.

My project is based on java, and I'm using aws-java-sdk for launching clusters and submitting hadoop jobs to the cluster.

Since, the output of the jobs need to be copied to s3, I am looking for an sdk that would receive source/destination paths as arguments and perform s3-distcp using the credential I set.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this on aws emr?

Comment: Not necessarily. I would like to execute the s3-distcp command from my code, just like I would from my local terminal using aws cli.

Comment: From what I have seen it looks like s3-distcp is proprietor to AWS. You could still use Hadoop distcp in your code https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html